# WMSGetFeatureInfo on multiple filtered layers

Tags: openlayers, gis, wms, getfeatureinfo

I am using OpenLayers to develop a thematic map and my problem is that I cannot get Info on multiple filtered (by cql_filter) WMS layers.

Instead I get the message "Layers and filters are mismatched, you need to provide one filter for each layer"

Which is the right method to provide one filter for each layer?

Answer (score 2):

When using cql_filter parameter, you must provide one filter expression for each layer in the request. The filters should be separated by semicolons, and for those layers that you don't want to filter, just add "INCLUDE" as the filter expression.

You can get more information at: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#wms-vendor-parameters